# How to put bar's value inside bar on HorizontalBarChartView of Swift iOS Charts?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I'm trying put the bar's value inside bar on my HorizontalBarChartView, because some values are clipping on the right side of the screen, but I not found solutions on the web search. Also, I want put the labels on left side of the chart, but I don't know how to this and I can't ask two things on the same question.

This is my setup Chart code:

```
func setupChart() {
    self.chartViewHorizontal.fitBars                   = true
    self.chartViewHorizontal.legend.enabled            = false
    self.chartViewHorizontal.isUserInteractionEnabled  = false
    self.chartViewHorizontal.animate(yAxisDuration: 1.5)

    self.chartViewHorizontal.rightAxis.enabled = false

    self.chartViewHorizontal.leftAxis.labelCount      = 5
    self.chartViewHorizontal.leftAxis.labelFont       = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 10.0)
    self.chartViewHorizontal.leftAxis.valueFormatter  = CustomAxisValueFormatter()

    self.chartViewHorizontal.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled    = false
    self.chartViewHorizontal.xAxis.enabled                 = false
}
```

results in:

[image]

I want this:

[image]

I'am using this lib: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 7):

Try to set below property false in your `chartview`:

```
self.chartViewHorizontal.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = false
```

this will help you to get your value labels inside `BarChart`.

For your 2nd issue to put your xAxis labels Left side of the `ChartView` you can use the below property to set it on the left side.

```
self.chartViewHorizontal.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
```

Try the above property and you will achieve your requirements.

Comment: as per my understanding you required your bar value label inside bar right ?

Comment: Yes, bar != chart. Bar is the blue retangles that representing the data.

Comment: You are alright. But the values are stacked above labels, please, check this image: https://imgur.com/a/qMkYrHl. You can help me fix it?

Comment: In that case you need to use value formatter and formate your value.